# WPF MeasureOverride/ArrangeOverride ActualWidth

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a custom panel that overrides `MeasureOverride` and `ArrangeOverride` methods.

Everything goes well, the only problem is that in the `OnRender` method of the child, `ActualWidth` does not change even if I call child.Arrange() with a smaller rect.

The docs does mention that is not recommended to call `UpdateLayout` inside `ArrangeOverride` - this method may change the ActualWidth of the child, but I would like a better and correct approach.

Does anyone know a solution for this?

Comment: Lacking a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, no one can tell you what is wrong with your code. Do keep in mind, element size may be controlled by the container object. Fix your question if you really want an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @Peter concerning example, I just realized after I posted the question what may be the problem.

It seems that I specified the Width of each child when created it and ActualWidth was always set to this instead of what was used in Measure and Arrange functions.

Thanks anyone for looking at this.